# How to add extension tags into mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I am using [comments](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aComments) and [AdsWherever](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAdsWherever) extension for adding comments and ads to my wiki. I have to add these extension tags `<ads media=ad>` and `<comments />` for adswherever and comments respectively while editing the article. As my wiki is public(and not private) every users also have to add these tags while editing an article. One of the disadvantage is users can intentionally or unintentionally can delete these tags

I want to know whether it is possible to incorpartate these tags automatically into the new article page without showing in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

To make things like comment look good you would probably need to create a custom skin. But if you are happy with just injecting things into the article, create an extension that hooks into e.g. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ParserBeforeTidy and add whatever you need there!